# Abstract classes can't be instantiated in Flutter

Tags: flutter, file, abstract-class, abstract

I am facing this issue when I'm trying to save in cache in local device, in the File path I get that error message as you can see in the screenshot, where am I wrong?

[image]

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/file.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:get/get_connect/http/src/response/response.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class ApiNewsPage {
  String baseUrl = "https://www.assofacile.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed"; // https://www.misya.info/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed

  Future getNewsArticles() async {
    String storeData = "storeDataArticles.json";
    var dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File file = File(dir.path + "/" + storeData);

    if (file.existsSync()) {
      print("Loading from cache");
      final data = file.readAsStringSync();
      final response = jsonDecode(data);
      return response;
    } else{
        print("Loading from network");
      try {
        var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var body;
          file.writeAsStringSync(body, flush: true, mode: FileMode.write);
          return jsonDecode(response.body);
        } else {
          return Future.error("Impossibile ricevere i dati, controllare la connessione");
        }
        // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
      } catch (SocketException) {
        return Future.error("Impossibile caricare gli articoli, prova a controllare la connessione");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of flutter you are using ? I think you need to upgrade your flutter sdk.

Comment: I'm using Flutter 3.3.3 • channel stable 
Tools • Dart 2.18.2 • DevTools 2.15.0

Comment: I just upgraded it, but nothing changed Flutter 3.3.9 • channel stable 
Tools • Dart 2.18.5 • DevTools 2.15.0